# Creating object with dummy values for unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am unit testing native c++ code with Visual studio 2013.

To unit test a method that gets a large data input as object, is there any tool available to create the object with dummy values for the fields in the class?

I checked [Google Mock](https://github.com/google/googlemock) which checks if a method is getting called, in which order methods are getting called, how many times a method is getting called, etc., But I haven't found any package or tool that helps to create object with dummy values to the fields.